# onActivityResult() is being called at an unexpected time

Tags: android, android-activity

In my main activity, I have:

```
    Intent settings_intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    settings_intent.putExtra("SomeID", some_int);
    startActivityForResult(settings_intent, 1);
```

And then, in my SettingsActivity, I have:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // pass back settings:
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("SomeThing", some_number);
    setResult(200, data);
    finish();
}
```

And finally, I overrode the following in my Main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    makeToast("called");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

However, the "called" toast happens as soon as my "Settings" activity starts, instead of when it finishes. I've spent quite a while on this now. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most likely your settings activity has it's launch mode set to `singleTask` in your manifest. This leads to a immediate cancel response when calling `startActivityForResult()`.

> Note that this method should only be used with Intent protocols that
>   are defined to return a result. In other protocols (such as
>   ACTION_MAIN or ACTION_VIEW), you may not get the result when you
>   expect. For example, if the activity you are **launching uses the
>   singleTask launch mode, it will not run in your task and thus you will
>   immediately receive a cancel result.**

*from the [`startActivityForResult()` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)*

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. launchMode was set to "singleInstance" actually, and it was not working. Just of curiosity, I changed it to `android:launchMode="singleTask"` after reading your answer, and it surprisingly worked. But now reading the doc, I'm worried if it will work on other devices.

Comment: I see how `singleInstance` can cause this too, since it's almost the same as `singleTask`. But to be honest, I have no idea why this works with `singleTask`, so I can't tell you if this works the same way on other devices.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==1)
        makeToast("called");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```