# Activity result is always 0

Tags: android, file, gallery, filechooser

I search whole day for this issue:

```
mUploadImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");

            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a Picture"),
                    FILE_SELECT_CODE);
        }
    });
```

Whenever I click on mUploadImage OnActivityResult() method it will be triggered immediately (Although i dont choose any file yet) and result code always 0. can anyone help me?

EDIT: (from comment below)

```
protected void onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) {
    if (arg0 == FILE_SELECT_CODE) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Selected a image. Result code: " + arg1);
        if (arg1 == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
```

Comment: What device do you use for tests?

Comment: My device is Xperia SL

Comment: Post some more code...

Comment: @Anukool: I remove all initialize code, in onCreate method I just do code inside onClick method above but still have same issue.

Comment: Can u post the onActivityResult...part

Comment: what it the value of FILE_SELECT_CODE? Is it possible that you are calling the chooser incorrectly? (Or that you don't have the necessary permissions?)

Comment: Check the request code ..whether it is equal to FILE_SELECT_CODE ?

Comment: protected void onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) {
  if (arg0 == FILE_SELECT_CODE) {
   Log.v(TAG, "Selected a image. Result code: " + arg1);
   if (arg1 == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

Comment: Ok.. What is the launchmode in android manifest?

Comment: @NeilTownsend: but actually, this code work on other Activity :(

Comment: @Anukool: singleInstance

Comment: post your manifest code

Comment: @VokilaM:it's too long to post :(

Comment: @Anukool: Oh god, thinking about your question and i found the reason is launchmode :(. Thanks all for help

Comment: It looks like it is returning Activity.RESULT_CANCELED: from the android docs: "The resultCode will be RESULT_CANCELED if the activity explicitly returned that, didn't return any result, or crashed during its operation." So, the chooser is failing cancelling itself for some reason. Are you sure you have the necessary permissions in this project / activity to launch that chooser?

Comment: @NeilTownsend the issue already fixed: because of launch mode's activity is singleInstance

Answer (score 1):

Check these answers. All of them say that there's a dependence between activity's launchMode and reporting result immediately

[onActivityResult() called prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354955/onactivityresult-called-prematurely)

[Android - startActivityForResult immediately triggering onActivityResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910840/android-startactivityforresult-immediately-triggering-onactivityresult)

[onActivityResult() is being called at an unexpected time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460250/onactivityresult-is-being-called-at-an-unexpected-time)